# Remove Meta title by hook in Yoast WordPress SEO

Tags: wordpress

I have WP site in which I'm using Yoast WordPress SEO plugin, but I want to remove META TITLE from some pages and want to add my OWN meta title by hook. I found a post here http://memberfind.me/disabling-wordpress-seo-plugins-on-a-page-by-page-basis/ but it is not working for me, Please help, any kind of help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yoast WordPress SEO Plugin supports a filter for meta title, so you could put something like this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title ', 'my_title_filter');

function my_title_filter($title) {
    // Change $title however you want
    return $title;
}
```